# Display a view above a React nativigation modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom snackbar component which has a zIndex higher than other views and an absolute position in the app.

The snackbar works fine, as long as no modals are opened. The problem is, I have nested navigation with nested modals and the snackbar component needs to be on top, all the time.

Currently, my screenOptions are: `{ presentation: 'modal' }`

Others like `containedModal` work, but gives me stacked headers for all the parent modals. I like the way `modal` presentation looks on iOS. Any ideas how an absolute View can be displayed above any modal from the root of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Z-index in RN doesn't work the same as it does on web - [see the docs for more](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#zindex).  Components are rendered as a tree, with the first items on the bottom and stacking until the last items are on top.

Therefore you can put a component on top of everything else by rendering it outside and after everything else. I.e.

```js
// App.js

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MainStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
      <Snackbar />
    </>
  );
};
```

You should style the component you want displayed on top with `position: 'absolute'`. If you want to pass touches through the component, you should also use `pointerEvents='box-none'` on the root View.